# C++ Getting started with WinDbg, setting source file path

Tags: c++, windbg

As a complete WinDbg beginner, I am just wondering, what is exactly going into the source file path? Is it the root folder of your sources? Is it all folders of your sources? (If the sources are in a directory structure)

And also, according to [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx): *In other words, if you use a source file MYCODE.CPP in C:\FOO, what's embedded in the PDB file is C:\FOO\MYCODE.CPP.* But if the path to the source file is an absolute path given in the PDB file, what do I need to set the sources for? Could I leave this blank then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your symbol path is all set either via _NT_SYMBOL_PATH or through WinDBG Symbol Path Option, you just need to specify the Root Source Path into the source file path.

This makes sense when there are multiple projects and you are debugging either a live process or a Crash Dump.

It is also recommended in these scenarios to maintain a Symbol Store where all the archives and current PDBs (Public or Private) are stored. This is achieved through symstore command. The path to the symstore should actually be appended to the symbol file path.

In case you are just debugging a single project, just pointing to the actual path which contains the source would work for you.

Comment: @Abhijt: I am still a bit confused. If the PDB file contains the absolute path to the source file used, why will the source file path be used for?

Comment: Unless you are debugging a remote process, debugging a crash dump where the crash happened on some other location or any case when the process/crash and the original source are not residing in the same local m/c, you need a source path. In the later case, WinDBG would pick the correct source from the PDB files.

Comment: So just to be sure I understood this: If I keep the PDB file on the same computer it was compiled on, and don't touch the source it was compiled with, and then copy the dump onto that machine, source path shouldn't matter?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As long as the source path in the PDB matches the original source path and is accessible, source path shouldn't matter.